# inserting a List<string> and List<Object> into Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a list of items `List<string> keys` and `List<Objects> obj` where the object has multiple items where it has another object, lets call it keyholder which has the name where it is the same value with keys.

```
List <string> key = {"a","b"}

List <Object> obj = object with items {name, id, IEnumerable<keyholder>}

keyholder has value name which can be the same with key.
```

I would like to create a

```
key.ToDictionary(e=>e, f=> obj.Where(obj.keyholder.Where(keyholder.name == key));
```

I want to add the object to the dictionary if and only if the keyholder.name has the same value with the key.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What is `keyholder` and `obj`? Where are they coming from

Comment: You have to show more of your code if you want us to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I was trying to edit my code but connection is pretty bad 
basically - List < key > has {"a","b","c"} and List<obj> has items where one of them is called another object keyholder 
obj{
  name
  id
  keyholder : {id, name = {"a"}
}
I want to add only the object where the name of keyholder is the same with the key

Comment: since obj ist `List<Object>` and not a List of your type that holds the keyholder member, it is going to be a little hard to check that member ...  can you introduce an interface or use a common base class that holds the keyholder member? (yes you could do it with reflection, but... ouch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help I got from you guys, I solved it by using a contain keyword since the IEnumerable can be in the list of items

```
key.ToDictionary(k => k, 
                 k => obj.Where(g => g.keyholder.Contains(k)).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. `Where` takes lambda-function as an argument.

If `keyholder` can store more than one values with given key, then you can convert your lists to the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue[]>`:

```
key.ToDictionary(k => k, 
                 k => obj.keyholder.Where(x => x.name == key).ToArray());
```

It will return a `Dictionary` having all items from `key` as a key, and array of values from `obj.keyholder` having the corresponding `name`.

Note that your `obj.keyholder` should be a `List<TValue>` where `TValue` is a type having a `name` property. You cannot apply this function to a `List<object>` since `object` has no `name` property.

Comment: this seems nice, let me try it and respond u.

Comment: yes i cannot call keyholder directly from obj, i need to use obj.where

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Just have noticed this, thanks. I have updated my answer, and will delete this answer if it is not applicable.

Comment: i need a way to figure out to get the value in the keyholder from the object directly.

Comment: if you can not change `Object` for something usefull, then there is only reflection to do this...

Comment: i can use contain but how can i get the key that is the key value of the dictionary for that index g=> g.where(f => f.keyholder.contains(??)

Comment: var dic = tags.ToDictionary(e => e, f => artifacts.Where(g=>g.Tags.Contains())); 
this is currently my code

Comment: I solved the problem already, this is the code: 
var dic = tags.ToDictionary(e => e, e => artifacts.Where(g=>g.Tags.Contains(e)).ToList());
thanks for the help everyone