# Cannot implicitly conver type System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<string,IList<string>> to System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<string,IList<string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have getting this error when I try to insert the value where I get from using the method `item.ToDictionary()` `b` to the `Dictionary<string,IList<string>>` `a` that I already initialized it.

```
Cannot implicitly conver type System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<string,List<string>> to System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<string,IList<string>>
```

```
var b = item.ToDictionary();
```

I used this function to create b and try to insert into a.

```
 public class Example {
    private Dictionary<string, IList<string>> a;
    private string c;
    private IList<string> d;

    public Example()
    {
        d = new List<string>();
        a = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
    }
    public void getDictionary()
    {
        var b = c.ToDictionary(e=>c, f=>d.ToList());
        a = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  We have nothing to go on here. `item.ToDictionary()` won't compile as the method requires at least one argument - assuming it's the LINQ extension method you're trying to use.

Comment: If I was going to hazard a guess based on the [question you asked 45mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287988/inserting-a-liststring-and-listobject-into-dictionary/39288630#39288630), you're actually trying to assign `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` which *is* different.

Comment: let me edit, you are right it is List<string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that d.ToList() returns a `List<string>`, so b will be of type `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, which is different from `Dictionary<string, IList<string>>`. You can cast it to a `IList<string>` to solve the problem:

```
public void getDictionary()
{
    var b = c.ToDictionary(e => c, f => (IList<string>) d.ToList());
    a = b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define b as

```
  var b = c.ToDictionary(e=>c, f=>(IList<string>)d);
```

Comment: assume i use a instead of b there